# Php Delete function. Capture the ID contained in an array and stored in a select field

Tags: php, arrays, variables

In a select field i have stored three different values of an array . 
The $listabrand['0'] contains the ID of the record.

```
<select name='brands_list'>
<option value="0">Select the Brand</option>
<?php 
while ($listabrand=mysqli_fetch_array($brands)){
echo '<option value="'.$listabrand['0'].','.$listabrand['1'].','.$listabrand['2'].'"> 
    '.$listabrand['1'].'</option>';
 }?>
</select>
```

I am implementing the DELETE Record function, selecting the value in the field 'brands_list' but at point it's difficult to me declare the ID into a variable since the brands_list field contains 3 different array values.

I put this but of course can't work because it doesn't know which value have to capture and it should be the $listabrand['0'].

```
$mod_id = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_REQUEST['brands_list']);
```

I embed the full php, it could be helpful

```
<?php
require '../sys/conn.php';
$mod_id = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_REQUEST['brands_list']);
if (isset($_GET['delete_brand'])){
    $delquery  = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM mg_terms where term_id= $mod_id");
    $delquery1 = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM mg_term_taxonomy where term_id= $mod_id");
    $delquery2 = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM mg_termmeta where term_id= $mod_id");
header('Location: ../pages/success.html');
}
else{header('Location: ../pages/error.html');
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The question is, how to select the ID in the above condition. Suggestions?

Comment: If you just want the first value in the string, you can use [strtok()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php). Example: `$id = strtok($_REQUST['brands_list'], ',');`. You should also use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Even `mysqli_real_escape_string()` has some security issues in certain situations.

Comment: I needed of the first value only that is the ID value. I will implement the security steps as second step. Thanks it works well.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're building a comma separated string, you need to break it apart again.

There are a couple of different ways to do this.

If you just want the first part, the id, you can use [strtok()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php):

```
$id = strtok($_REQUEST['brands_list'], ',');
```

If you want all the parts, you can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):

```
list($id, $part2, $part3) = explode(',', $_REQUEST['brands_list']);
```